# Use Reflection to get methods excluding local functions in C# 7.0?

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-7.0

Is there a way to use reflection to get private static methods in a class, without getting any local functions defined within those methods?

For instance, I have a class like so:

```
public class Foo {
    private static void FooMethod(){
        void LocalFoo(){
           // do local stuff
        }
        // do foo stuff
    }
}
```

If I use reflection to grab the private static methods like so:

```
var methods = typeof(Foo).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Select(m=>m.Name).ToList();
```

Then I end up with something like:

```
FooMethod
<FooMethod>g__LocalFoo5_0
```

With the gnarly compiler-generated name of the local function included.

So far, the best I have been able to come up with is to add a Where clause that would filter out the local functions, like:

```
    var methods = typeof(Foo).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        .Where(m=>!m.Name.Contains("<")
        .Select(m=>m.Name).ToList();
```

or:

```
    var methods = typeof(Foo).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        .Where(m=>!m.Name.Contains("__")
        .Select(m=>m.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: what it returns is correct, filtering is also a must-do as well as a preferred and standard way (in many scenarios we don't use BindingFlags and just go for LINQ queries to filter for the desired members).

Comment: There is more than one way to do this.  The wonky name is one way but that's an implementation detail.  Surely a desirable approach is to filter out any method that was generated by the compiler instead of user code.  Use MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes() and filter out the ones that have the [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute]

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
var methods = typeof(Foo).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Where(x => !x.IsAssembly)
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Result:

```
"FooMethod"
```

`IsAssembly` property summary:

> Gets a value indicating whether the potential visibility of this method or constructor
>   is described by System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.Assembly; that is, the method
>   or constructor is visible at most to other types in the same assembly, and is
>   not visible to derived types outside the assembly.

Comment: This assumes that all local functions are `internal`, [which is not true](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTABAYg9jEG8CwAoC6IgCzTgWQFMAXACxgBMAKASkVQwcxwBkYBjAQwBtYYa60jIQBUYAZSIAnAJYA7AOY0A3PSEQAvqvSaU6oA==).

Comment: The generated class signature in your example is `internal class Foo`. How can a function inside an `internal class` not be internal as well?

Comment: It can be `private`, in which case `IsAssembly` will return `false`.

Comment: That's why it is `*!*x.Assembly`. OP wants to filter local functions *inside* a `private static` function.

Comment: For such local function, `x.IsAssembly` will be `false`, so `!x.IsAssembly` will be `true` and so it will be included in the results.

Comment: [Not, it won't](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EqWT9A). Thanks for your downvote when you don't even know what you are talking about. Read the property's summary again: `the method or constructor is visible at most to other types in the same assembly`, hence the negation operator. Next time provide a working example where the test will fail, instead of a useless SharpLab code based on your guessing.

Comment: Nice try but that doesn't fill OP's requirement to `use reflection to get private static methods in a class`. 1 - Your `FooMethod()` method is not static. 2 - You deliberately changed the `BindingFlags` (included `BindingFlags.Instance`) to fit YOUR needs, not OP's, thus manipulating the result. 3 - Grow up